# How to eliminate a prefix string with all 0s

Tags: regex, matlab

There have a set of strings, some of them are prefixed with 0, and others are not.  For instance,

> 012AB
>
> AB0
>
> 00230
>
> 0045
>
> abc

I want to remove all of the 0s if they are the prefix of a string. If a string does not have 0s at the prefix position, then the string will be kept the same.  Therefore, the above strings should be transferred into

> 12AB
>
> AB0
>
> 230
>
> 45
>
> abc

How to implement the above functionality using regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html):

```
a = {'012AB','AB0','00230','0045','abc'};
a = regexprep(a,'^0+','')

ans = 

    '12AB'    'AB0'    '230'    '45'    'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression that finds the first character that is not zero and then matches everything after it...

```
regexp(str, '[^0].*', 'match');
```

Comment: The only problem of this is that the answer will be cell array of cells, not cell array of strings. To convert you can add `a = [a{:}]`, where `a` is the output of the statement in the answer.